Can r1 == 0 and r2 == 0 occur without volatile in this Java program?
Do I understand correctly that if I run run1() and run2() in parallel, the result r1 == 0 and r2 == 0 is impossible under any circumstances, even though a and b are not volatile?
public class Example {

    private int a = 0;
    private int b = 0;

    public void run1() {
        b = 1; // (1)
        int r2 = a; // (2)
    }

    public void run2() {
        a = 2; // (3)
        int r1 = b; // (4)
    }
}

My conclusion is based on this statement from the Java Memory Model, p. 17.4.5: "If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y)."

(1) and (2) are actions of the same thread and (1) comes before (2) in program order. Therefore, (1) happens-before (2).
Similarly, (3) happens-before (4).

This program contains only four actions, resulting in 4! possible executions. By analysing each possible execution, I conclude that any execution leading to r1 == 0 and r2 == 0 would violate the happens-before relationships described above and is therefore illegal.

If you're running in parallel, then you're using multiple threads, and thus your reliance on actions of the same thread breaks down. So, yes it is entirely possible that r1 == 0 and r2 == 0, because the thread running run1 may not see the changes from the other thread running run2.

I was going to say the same.  If x and y are actions of the same thread Nope, you just said you are running in two separate threads.  Look at the other section of the Java memory model, you're looking at the wrong one.

"This program contains only four actions, resulting in 4! possible executions." - you've got the typical newbie "things happen in some order" mental model, which seems intuitively obvious but is for all intents and purposes completely wrong for concurrent programming. A multithreaded program is not required to behave as if all actions took place in some global order.

What I think could happen:  the optimizer sees some advantage in hoisting a and b into a register.  Both sequences are run, and in their respective threads the code "makes sense" -- r1 and r2 are allowed to be zero at least some of the time. Then later the optimizer decides it needs those registers back and finally writes a and b with the assigned values.  Result: both r1 and r2 have a zero value.

@MarkRotteveel, do you agree that, according to p. 17.4.5 of the Java Memory Model, (1) happens-before (2)? They are actions of the same thread and (1) clearly comes before (2) in program order, so they should have the happens-before relationship, shouldn't they?

Your example is basically similar to the Example 17.4-1 given in JLS 17.4. Memory Model ("The semantics of the Java programming language allow compilers and microprocessors to perform optimizations that can interact with incorrectly synchronized code in ways that can produce behaviors that seem paradoxical. ... compilers are allowed to reorder the instructions in either thread, when this does not affect the execution of that thread in isolation. ...")

(1) happens-before (2)? Basically, no.  As seen by the second thread, it's allowed for that second thread to see code as if (2) happens before (1).  Yes, the thread executing that code sees (1) and then (2), because it's a single thread of execution.  But any other thread may see the order differently.

@yaskovdev Yes, but your actual question concerns cross-thread visibility between (1) and (4), and (3) and (2), and there no such happens-before relationship exist. So the happens before between (1) and (2) / (3) and (4) within their respective threads is entirely irrelevant for the analysis here.

Your analysis is wrong because it misses these two points from 17.4.5. Happens-before Order:

It should be noted that the presence of a happens-before relationship between two actions does not necessarily imply that they have to take place in that order in an implementation. If the reordering produces results consistent with a legal execution, it is not illegal.

That first point means that an implementation can execute the
code fragment
    b = 1; // (1)
    int r2 = a; // (2)

in reverse order
    int r2 = a; // (2)
    b = 1; // (1)

Since action (2) does not depend on a result of action (1) this produces a result consistent with a legal execution and is therefore allowed (what any calling method on the same thread observes is independent of the execution order of those two statements since it can only observe any changes after both statements have finished).

More specifically, if two actions share a happens-before relationship, they do not necessarily have to appear to have happened in that order to any code with which they do not share a happens-before relationship. Writes in one thread that are in a data race with reads in another thread may, for example, appear to occur out of order to those reads.

Two unsynchronized threads executing run1() and run2() in parallel do not share a happens-before relationship. You can therefore not expect that one thread sees the actions of the other thread in any specific order.

Thank you for the clarification. Do I understand correctly that even if both a and b were declared volatile, the result r1 == 0 and r2 == 0 would still be possible?

Update: I found a tool called jcstress and tested the version where both a and b are volatile. The result r1 == 0 and r2 == 0 is impossible, presumably because, with volatile, the program is "correctly synchronized." When a program is correctly synchronized, the JMM guarantees that "all executions of the program will appear to be sequentially consistent."

JCstress will only show that a problem can happen, you can't rely on it to determine that a problem can't happen.

Declaring both variables as volatile will indeed establish the appropriate happens-before edges.
